# To forward or move or not; how to determine which is preferred within the context of a class's usage?

Tags: c++, c++17, std, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

```
class Test {
public:
    typedef std::set<std::pair<double, double>> DataSet;

    explicit Test(const DataSet&& d) {
        for (auto &itr : d) {
            std::cout << "value1 = " << itr.first << '\n';
            std::cout << "value2 = " << itr.second << '\n';
        }
    }

};

int main() {
    //using namespace util;
    try {
        // Forwarding
        Test obj( std::forward<Test::DataSet>(
            { 
              { 10.0, 20.0 },
              { 30.0, 40.0 },
              { 50.0, 60.0 }
            }
        ));

        std::cout << '\n';

        // Move
        Test obj2(std::move(Test::DataSet(
            {
              { 10.0, 20.0 },
              { 30.0, 40.0 },
              { 50.0, 60.0 }
            }
           )
        ));

    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Neither, simply pass the initializer-list directly - https://godbolt.org/z/AZW5xu. Also `const X &&` is usually wrong, you want `X&&` or `const X&` depending on the use-case.

Comment: Holt; I know I can just pass the pairs in via initializer list; however between the two which one is better and why? As for the `const x&&`, and `const x&` I wasn't particularly concerned with them... I wrote constructor this way just to be able to compile both `std::move` and `std::forward`... It's more just about performance, the readability, and the esthetics between the two different algorithms.

Comment: *"between the two which one is better and why?"* - As I said, neither, the best one is the version without them. There is no point in using `std::move` or `std::forward` in this case, so there is no point comparing them...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither.

`Test::DataSet(/*...*/)` is already a rvalue that can bind to a rvalue reference. The only thing `std::move` does is to turn a lvalue into a xvalue (which is a rvalue), so that it can bind to a rvalue reference, which lvalues cannot. So `std::move` is redundant.

`std::forward` does the same only conditional on its template argument. So it is redundant (at best) as well.

`const DataSet&&` as parameter makes no sense. You want either `DataSet&&` which binds only to rvalues or `const DataSet&`, which binds to rvalues and lvalues.

If you want to make use of the fact that the passed reference might be a rvalue (i.e. by moving from its members), then you need two overloads of your function. One taking `DataSet&&` which is called with rvalue arguments and one taking `const DataSet&` which is called with lvalue arguments.

In the specific case of the `Test` function in your question, I don't see how there would be any benefit to moving from the members or do any other modification of the `DataSet` state, so I would go with simply `const DataSet&` as parameter and never bother with `std::move`ing or `std::forward`ing into that function specifically.

Comment: user `holt` gave me basically this same answer in a comment; However, I like how you explained how and why they aren't in this particular case.

Comment: I don't use them all that often; so at times I'll ask things like this for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

[Code samples edited in response to comments]
A useful bit of [advice](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f15-prefer-simple-and-conventional-ways-of-passing-information) from the ISO Core Guidelines. This would suggest that you should prefer (const T&), but if you really need speed add a (T&&) specifically. This way you can pass small sets as (L-Value)

```
const auto data = Test::DataSet{ 
          { 10.0, 20.0 },
          { 30.0, 40.0 },
          { 50.0, 60.0 }};
Test obj( data );
```

or (R-Value)

```
Test obj( Test::DataSet{ 
          { 10.0, 20.0 },
          { 30.0, 40.0 },
          { 50.0, 60.0 },
        });
```

Adding the extra move makes the second kind of call more efficient, but the advice is to only use this type of optimization if it is required. You should avoid having different semantics for one constructor than for the other, and the easiest way to avoid that is to only have one constructor.

Personally, even after 20+ years of C++ programming, I found the table in the link so useful I printed it out and stuck it to my monitor.

Comment: I truly appreciate the tip. Yeah in most cases `T&` will suffice, but sometimes I might want to get a boost in performance with `T&&`. It depends on the custom data sets - structures I'm passing or moving around. Working on the internals of a 3D Graphics Engine via OpenGL - Vulkan. So, I'm experimenting with ideas for use within the engine to try and keep it generic with optimal performance, etc...

Comment: I just booked marked the GitHub page by Stroustrup and Sutter! If those two maintain it; you know it ought to be good! I've been self-taught in C++ for almost that long... I'm still learning. I can write a 3D graphics engine from scratch, but when diving deeper into the STL... I've learned a lot on my own yet there is still so much that I haven't. I knew about `move` and `forward` already; I've used them here and there, but when you do not use them all that often it becomes more about remembering which one serves which purpose and the difference in performance.

Comment: This link has a nice description of perfect forwarding (when you should use std::forward) https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/perfect-forwarding-and-universal-references-in-c

Comment: @FrancisCugler If you sought to understand `move` and `forward`, you should probably look at dedicated resources online, not try to learn-it by trial-and-error. For instance, there is no "performance" competition between `move` and `forward`, as both serves different (yet related) purpose. Also, `std::forward` as (almost?) no use outside of templated code.

Comment: Also, never talk about _boost in performance_ if you haven't profiled your **compiler optimized** code with a profiler and verified that it actually is a bottleneck.

Comment: @Timo I think you might have misunderstood the intent... I never asked that in the question itself. It was just a hint within the comments only to suggest which of the two methods gives better performance and in which context, using the smallest footprint...

Comment: Regarding your second example, I am not sure I understood your intent. `MakeALargeSet()` would most likely return by-value as well. So you are demonstrating calls of the rvalue reference overload (or the `const` lvalue reference one if that doesn't exist) in both examples. Is that intended?

Comment: @Walnut : I was hoping no one would spot that :-). No, I changed the first example to show the std::forward was not necessary, and swapped an R-Value for an L-Value. (Using an R-Value as a (const&) parameter is still a valid thing to do of coarse. I will amend my answer